# How to create new data frame with custom columns out of another data frame, on filtered data per each column

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

I've tried to look for a similar question but I couldn't find anything similar.

I have a data frame df with hundreds of rows and several variables. The first variable is **level** which goes from 1 to 8.

Eg:

```
df<- data.frame(level = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), CODE = c("1234", "3452", "1234", "7654","6547","6546", "7683", "6543", "7683", "6543", "7683"), ADD_ALLOW_MEAL = c(NA, "Y", "Y", "N", "N", NA, NA, "Y", "Y", "N", 'N'), ALLOW_MEALLOW = c(NA, 40, 60, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50, 70, NA, NA)) 

> df
   level     CODE ADD_ALLOW_MEAL     ALLOW_MEALLOW
1      1     1234           <NA>                NA
2      1     3452              Y                40
3      1     1234              Y                60
4      2     7654              N                NA
5      2     6547              N                NA
6      3     6546           <NA>                NA
7      4     7683           <NA>                NA
8      5     6543              Y                50
9      6     7683              Y                70
10     7     6543              N                NA
11     8     7683              N                NA
```

What I need is to create a **new** data frame which will have only 8 rows (8 levels from df). Normally I'd use simple:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(level) %>% 
  summarise()
```

The problem is I need to create several very custom columns on the filtered data, all per **level**.

Example:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(level) %>% 
  summarise(
    Meal_Average =  filter(., ADD_ALLOW_MEAL =="Y" & ALLOW_MEALLOW>0) %>% {ifelse(str_detect(.$CODE, "2")=="TRUE", round(mean(.$ALLOW_MEALLOW, na.rm = TRUE),3), NA_real_ )}  
  )
```

I get an error of:

> ```
> Column `Meal_Average` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 4
> ```

My desired result would be:

```
 level    Meal_Average 
1      1   50
2      2   NA
3      3   NA
4      4   NA
5      5   NA
6      6   NA
7      7   NA
8      8   NA
```

Any ideas how can I do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using `dplyr`. What I did here is I just used your conditions to replace the `ALLOW_MEALLOW` value to 0 (so that it does not impact the mean), i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate(ALLOW_MEALLOW = replace(ALLOW_MEALLOW, ADD_ALLOW_MEAL == 'N' & ALLOW_MEALLOW < 0 | !grepl('2', CODE), 0)) %>% 
 group_by(level) %>% 
 summarise(new_mean = mean(ALLOW_MEALLOW, na.rm = TRUE))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 8 x 2
>   level new_mean
>   <dbl>    <dbl>
> 1     1       50
> 2     2        0
> 3     3        0
> 4     4        0
> 5     5        0
> 6     6        0
> 7     7        0
> 8     8        0
> ```

**NOTE:** You can replace 0 with NA as usual

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is a new way for me to use replace, very useful! Do you know how could I use that solution to create more custom columns? I need plenty of them in one new data frame (that's why I wanted to use one "summarize"). In your solution using **mutate** it would be several separate data frames, right? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Marta. No, mutate does not create data frames. Try `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(new = mean(Sepal.Width))` Vs `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(new = mean(Sepal.Width))`. If you want to apply the function to more columns there are `mutate_at`, `mutate_if`, `mutate_all` (same with summarise)